# What is the meaning of the value inside memory content of a struct - C

Tags: c, memory, struct

I decided to check what value I'll get when I print the **memory content of an instance of a struct**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
 int value;
} Data;

int main(){
  Data *d = (Data*) malloc(sizeof(Data));
  printf("%d", *d);
  
  return 0;
}
```

The result I got is a random value (To me) and I tried to do all kinds of experiments but not so I could understand what is behind this value. But maybe I just do not understand the way structs are stored in memory. I'd love an explanation.

Comment: It's not initialized, so yes, it's a "random" value. Technically, it's Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: It's uninitialized, so there's no telling what value you'll get. Likely whatever happened to be lying around in the memory you got. Possibly a consistent zero on some systems, but don't rely on that.

Comment: If you do `int d; printf("%d", d)` what output do you expect?

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer to memory allocated to store your struct. Deferencing the pointer itself does not guarantee to print `int value`, you should do `d->value` for this. Regardless, you have not initialized your struct so the behavior is undefined by the C standard. It is most likely going to be "garbage"/unused memory that was previously at the allocated location.

Comment: @klutt What format specifier should I use for this case?

Comment: @RonDev you cannot print a struct, you only can print an element of the struct, for exampler in your case: `printf("%d", d->value);`.

Comment: `Data d = (Data*) malloc(sizeof(Data));` Data is not a valid type name. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @wildplasser I am using GCC compiler and I use C std libraries. Why not valid type name? It is a struct tag.

Comment: No, you are not: `Data.c: In function ‘main’:
Data.c:10:3: error: unknown type name ‘Data’
   Data d = (Data*) malloc(sizeof(Data));
   ^
`

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you for the comment. You are right, I forgot to add the struct keyword at the beginning.

Comment: @RDev the solution was to add the `struct` keyword, not to obfuscate the code with a pointless typedef.

Answer (score 3):

The memory returned from `malloc` is **uninitialized**.  Reading it before it is set will result in seeing *indeterminate values* (i.e. the random values you're seeing), and in some cases can trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  There's no guarantee you'll even read the same value twice from the same memory location.

The way you're printing is also incorrect.  You're passing an instance of a struct to `printf` when the given format specifier expects an `int`.  That also causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: "in some cases"? Doesn't it always?

Comment: @klutt Not if the memory location in question had its address taken and if the lvalue used to access it is properly aligned and doesn't have trap representations.

Comment: @dbush Thanks. Is the memory address of this instance is the beginning of a continuous memory?

Comment: @RonDev You requested `sizeof(Data)` bytes from `malloc`, so the returned address points to that many bytes that you can write to.